# How to view a remote jenkins job (on machine 1) in jenkins pipeline (on machine 2)

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I have two jenkins instances, machine-1 and machine-2
Job-1 from machine-1 will trigger job-1 on machine-2.
Once job-1 on machine-2 is finished, it will trigger job-2 on machine-1.

I would like to view all these three jobs in pipeline viewed on machine-1

I used Build Pipeline Plugin and Delivery Pipeline Plugin.
Using it I can view the jobs(Job-1 and job-2) on machine-1 . But i can't view the job-1 on Machine-2.

Is there any way to view the remote job in the pipleline?

Please advise.